# Extracting "title" data from JSON

Tags: python, json, api, difference

i have this API..

https://manager.upbit.com/api/v1/

and I want to extract the title from it and compare it to see if there are any changes or updates to api ... i am getting error

```
before_set = before['data']['title']
KeyError: 'title'
```

my code is the following:

```
import requests
import json

try:
    with open('notice.json', 'r') as current_notice:
        before = json.loads(current_notice.read())
except IOError:
    before = requests.get('https://manager.upbit.com/api/v1/').json()
    with open('notice.json', 'w') as current_notice:
        current_notice.write(json.dumps(before))
    print("First run....")

after = requests.get('https://manager.upbit.com/api/v1/').json()

before_set = before['data']['title']
after_set = after['data']['title']

new_set = after_set - before_set

while True:
    try:
        if not new_set:
            print("No change... Exiting.")
        if new_set:
            print("There are changes")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Comment: Should it not be before['data']['list'][index]['title'] where index = 0,1,2... You want to compare all the titles in the api?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the key is available in the dictionary before accessing it.

```
if 'title' in before['data']:
    before_set = before['data'].get('title')
```

Better than that, try using .get() method instead, it will return None, if the requested key is not present.

```
before_set = before['data'].get('title')
```

You can also return some "default value", if case 'title' is not present in before['data']

```
before_set = before['data'].get('title', "No Title")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, json
url = "https://api-manager.upbit.com/api/v1/notices?page=1"
response = json.loads(requests.get(url).content)
title_data = [item.get("title", None).encode("utf-8") for item in response["data"]["list"]]
print(title_data)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.